# how can I get submit method in jsp?

Tags: jsp, post, methods, parameters, get

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type=text name="nm" />
</form>
```

request.getParameter("nm");

I can get the parameter named nm, but I can't confirm it's confirm method ,post or get??

Comment: Always use `Servlet`. Sub-class the `HttpServlet` and override `doPost`.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getMethod()` returns the web method used (`post`, `get` etc...)

Comment: that what I am seeking

Comment: If this answer solved your question you can upvote it and mark as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

From JavaEE 6 docs [HttpServletRequest#getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29)

> **Returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made**, for example, GET, POST, or PUT. Same as the value of the CGI variable REQUEST_METHOD.

Answer (score 0):

By default if you dont specify anything in your form ,

```
<form action="">
   <input type=text name="nm" />
</form>
```

it will be `get` . (i.e) you need to override `doGet` . ti know the method used , you can achieve it through `request.getMethod()` which *returns a String specifying the name of the method with which this request was made* . see this to understand the difference [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get/3477374#3477374) and use the appropriate one.

Hope this helps !!